# Search large number of ID search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

Thanks for looking at my query. I have 20k+ unique identification id that I is provided by client, I want to look for all these id's in MongoDB using single query. I tried looking using $in but then it does not seems feasible to put all the 20K Id in $in and search. Is there a better version of achieving.

Answer (score 0):

If the id field is indexed, an IN query should be very fast, but i don't think it is a good idea to perform a query with 20k ids in one time, as it may consume quite a lot of resources like memory, you can split the ids into multiple groups with a reasonable size and do the query separately and you still can perform the queries parallelly in application level.

Answer (score 0):

Consider importing your 20k+ id into a collection(says using `mongoimport` etc). Then perform a `$lookup` from your root collection to the search collection. Depending on whether the `$lookup result` is empty array or not, you can proceed with your original operation that requires `$in`.

Here is [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CGAk4xfMMya) for your reference.